# Android queue of user objects that overwrites duplicates instead of ignoring them like LinkedHashSet?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a queue for outgoing bluetooth messages in Android.  The UI can generate a bunch of messages to be sent out via bluetooth.  Sometimes these are of the same message type, but with different data.  If I have 10 of the same message type waiting to go out, I don't want to send all 10, I just want to send the last one. This is mainly to save bandwidth as BLE is fairly limited.

The queue contains message objects that have message_type and message_data Strings.  The behaviour I'm looking for, but can't seem to figure out is: When adding a new object to the queue, it should check the existing items in the queue to see if any are of the same message_type.  If so, the new object would overwrite that object in the queue (or delete the existing object and add the new one to the end of the queue. either would work)  If an object with a matching message_type isn't found, then the new object would just be added to the end of the queue.

I haven't found anything that does this.  The closest I have found is a LinkedHashSet, but this would just not add the new element instead of replacing the existing element with the new one.  Maybe this behaviour can be modified?

The Bluetooth Message Obj:

```
    public class BluetoothMessageObj {
        private String message_type;
        private String message_data;
    }
```

EDIT

Here's what I ended up going with:

```
private LinkedList<BluetoothMessageObj> outgoingMessageQueue = new LinkedList<>();

public void addMessageToOutgoingMessageQueue(BluetoothMessageObj newObj){
    for (int i = 0; i < outgoingMessageQueue.size(); i++) {
        BluetoothMessageObj existingObj = outgoingMessageQueue.get(i);
        if( existingObj.getMessage_type().equals( newObj.getMessage_type() ) ){
            outgoingMessageQueue.remove(i);   // remove the existing message
            break;
        }
    }
    outgoingMessageQueue.add(newObj);          // add the new message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you can create your own logic as following:

```
private void replaceValue(ArrayList<BluetoothMessageObj> list, BluetoothMessageObj newBluetoothMessage) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).getMessage_type().equalsIgnoreCase(newBluetoothMessage.getMessage_type())) {
                list.set(i, newBluetoothMessage);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now everytime you add new element pass existing list of elements and new element you want to add and this would do it for you.

Comment: Thanks.  ArrayList might not be the best choice because I need to use it as a queue.  But perhaps applying this type of logic using a LinkedList as a Queue could work?  I'll try it out and post results.